# Prorate the NetPremium for the whole year and allocate points to the sales agent to asses their performance

Tags: sql-server

I want to Prorate the Premium for all the sales agent below if they have a netpremium for that particular month. I have the goal metrics to which I have to compare the prorated premium and allocate the points to each sales agent, so that they can keep track of their points and make improvement to their scores or know where they stand.

I have provided below table that has agent, Month start and end dates, and their NetPremium $ amount. If an agent has NULL NetPremium for a particular month start to end date, then it means that an agent was not assigned or did not work for that month. I want to prorate their net premium only for their worked months and compare to the final goal metrics as below. The following goal/target metrics is calculated for the whole year. Any thoughts or insight would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**GOAL/TARGET Tiers**

```
            NetPremium          $1,500,000      $1,350,000      $1,250,000      $1,000,000 
            Points Earned           19              17              14              12
            Medals              Platinum           Gold           Silver          Bronze
```

**RAW DATA**

```
        Agent               MonthStartDate  MonthEndDate    NetPremium  

        Dianne              2019-04-01      2019-04-30      193912.00   
        Dolly, Elizebeth    2019-04-01      2019-04-30      NULL    
        David, Michael      2019-04-01      2019-04-30      150984.00   
        Mannaz, Sarah       2019-04-01      2019-04-30      NULL    

        Dianne              2019-03-01      2019-03-31      NULL        
        Dolly, Elizebeth    2019-03-01      2019-03-31      382682.99
        David, Michael      2019-03-01      2019-03-31      18976.00    
        Mannaz, Sarah       2019-03-01      2019-03-31      753802.0

        Dianne              2019-02-01      2019-02-28      82628.9     
        Dolly, Elizebeth    2019-02-01      2019-02-28      2672.99
        David, Michael      2019-02-01      2019-02-28      863.00  
        Mannaz, Sarah       2019-02-01      2019-02-28      7572.0

        Dianne              2019-01-01      2019-01-31      8736.9      
        Dolly, Elizebeth    2019-01-01      2019-01-31      8269.99
        David, Michael      2019-01-01      2019-01-31      NULL    
        Mannaz, Sarah       2019-01-01      2019-01-31      NULL
```

Comment: Could you please provide expected result data